# Show/Hide Div's even if input is required?

Tags: jquery, html, forms, show-hide

I have a form in which divs are shown/hidden based on what is selected in a drop down box.  Using .show and .hide via jquery works great to show/hide the fields, however the input on these forms need to be **required.**  What's happening is when one of the fields is hidden, the form won't submit - more than likely because this "hidden" field still required.

Is there a way to disable/remove this field all together instead of hiding the div when a certain item is selected in the drop down?  I've attempted using the .attr("disabled", true) with no luck.  Any help is appreciated.

JQuery snippet:

```
  $('#productpr1').on('change',function() {

  if(this.value=='PRODUCT1')
        {
    $('.initial').show();
    $('.name').show();
    $('.mono').hide();
    $('.comment').show();

        }
  else if (this.value=='PRODUCT2') 
         {
    $('.initial').hide();
    $('.name').hide();
    $('.mono').show();
    $('.comment').show();

        }
  else if (this.value=='PRODUCT3') 
         {
    $('.initial').show();
    $('.name').show();
    $('.mono').show();
    $('.comment').show();
        }
  else
         {
    $('.initial').show();
    $('.name').show();
    $('.mono').show();
    $('.comment').show();
         }

  });
```

HTML:

```
<select name="productpr1" id="productpr1">
<option value="Please Select:0">Please select your product</option>
<option value="PRODUCT1">PRODUCT1</option>
<option value="PRODUCT2">PRODUCT2</option>
<option value="PRODUCT3">PRODUCT3</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>

<div class="initial">
<div id="Profont"><b>Initial:</b>
</div>
<input name="product1[]" type="text" required id="thisone" size="5">
</div>

<div class="name">
<div id="Profont"><b>Name:</b>
<br>
</div>
<input name="product1[]" type="text" required id="thisone" size="5">
</div>


<div class="mono">
<div id="Profont"><b>Mono Initials:</b>
<br>
</div>
<input name="product1[]" type="text" required id="thisone" size="5">
</div>

<div class="comment">
<div id="Profont"><b>Additional Comments:</b>
<br>
</div>
<input type="text" name="product1[]" size="10" id="comments">
</div>

<input type="submit" value="Add to Cart" name="Cart" class="INDVbutton" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could remove the `required` attribute when you hide it.

```
$('.name').hide().find(':input').attr('required', false);
```

and add it back when you show it:

```
$('.name').show().find(':input').attr('required', true);
```

Comment: I really like this option as it doesn't require me to change much.  The fields hide/show like they should, however after hitting submit, nothing happens.

Comment: I just noticed that `.name` isn't the input, it's the DIV that contains it. I've updated the answer to find the inputs and change their required attributes.

Comment: Worked perfectly!  Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with Jquery's `.remove()` ? see [here](https://api.jquery.com/remove/)

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I looked into this and it does work and submit works - the only problem however is if you change the content of the drop down a second time, the field is still removed and will not "re-add" the input field.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I have just finished working on something very similar to the above.  If the input fields which are not currently being shown are not required upon form submission, you could rework your functions to only extract values from the currently visible controls?  You could assign a different class to your existing divs to locate the one(s) that's visible with JQuery (should also work with multiple divs currently visible).  See sample Javascript function below which you may be able to use:

ASPX:

```
<div id="DivWithID1" class="DisplayableDiv">
    <asp:TextBox id="textBoxEntry" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var visibleDivs= $(".DisplayableDiv:visible");
// are any divs being shown
if (visibleDivs.length !== 0)
{
    // loop through all visible divs
    for(i = 0; i < visibleDivs.length; ++i)
    {
        switch(visibleDivs[i].id) {
            // assign each div an ID which you can extract here
            case 'DivWithID1':
            // extract the values inside each input text box (can also replace with your controls)
            $(visibleDivs[i]).find("input[type=text]").each(function () {
                var value = $(this).val();
            }
            break;
            ... add more cases here
        }
    }
    // ... continue with post functionality
}
```

Hope this helps.